# Hover on component inside a div that has a transform: translate3d effect on hover / Vue.js queue events(?)

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions, translate-animation

I have a modal component inside a div that has a transform: translate3d effect (with transition!) on hover. That div is rendered with vue.js list rendering method. When I open my modal and hover over it, it is snapping in turns to parent div and it's appropriate position.

This is how modal should work: https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/mwLbw11k/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=mwLbw11k

```
  <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
  </modal>
```

And this is my situation: https://jsfiddle.net/olivetum/bxwjb9co/

I decided to add css method :not(.className) and bind blocking class to parent div. It does the trick but there is still some glitch on modal enter/leave: https://jsfiddle.net/olivetum/3yrrnhsj/

Any ideas how can I remove that glitch?

Comment: You are required to post a complete example of your problem code here, not third party sites that may change or disappear and make your question and the answers useless to anyone else. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The `<modal>` element is inside the `<div>` with `.absoluteDiv`, and the `.absoluteDiv` styles/animations are conflicting with the modal styles/animations. If you put the `<div>` with `.absoluteDiv` around just the `<button>`, it should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/o45gqj9o/3/